# How to add a deleted date flag column

Tags: sql-server, ssis, derived-column

I have some incremental extracts that I would be importing into SQL Server into a new table called `Import.table` and then I load it into a fact table. The `Import.table` table gets truncated everyday and that's the reason I was asked to maintain the fact table which is `Fact.table`. This would have the history data. I am creating a reporting table from the fact table called `fact.tablereporting` which is supposed to have a `Deleted` and `DeletedDate` columns. In the beginning I was asked to create only the `Deleted` flag column which was simple, so I created a derived column with a case statement.

```
select *, deleted= case when ([ClientId] in (select [ClientId] from fact.table
except 
select clientid from Import.table)) then '1' else '0' end
from fact.table
```

Later I was asked to add the `DeletedDate` column based on the day the record was marked deleted. This is creating my problem. Because the extracts are incremental and the same rows get processed everyday, when I am trying to create it as a derived column the `DeletedDate` column gets updated with the present day's date.

```
select *, deleted= case when ([ClientId] in (select [ClientId] from fact.table
except 
select clientid from import.table)) then '1' else '0' end
, deleteddate= case when ([ClientId] in (select [ClientId] from fact.table
except 
select clientid from Import.table)) then getdate() else null end
from fact.Table
```

Is there a way that I can ignore the rows that have already been flagged with a date and update only those rows that were freshly deleted? I am not sure if derived column is the right way to do it too. I would really appreciate help on this.

Comment: Do you have the freedom to modify the existing table structures as part of your solution?

Comment: Not the reporting table but the other two yes